# How can I make yEd look more integrated into Ubuntu?

Tags: java, themes, fonts, yed

[yEd](/media/Share/Bibliothek/Tutorials/PC/Software/LibreOffice/Hotkeys.odt) is a powerful graph editor that is coded in Java and supports a variety of platforms, including Ubuntu. However, by default it looks quite alien to the Ubuntu desktop as it doesn't appear to use a GTK theme. Unfortunately there is no setting to change is.

Is there anything I can do to make yEd more integrated into the Ubuntu desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yEd uses Java's metallic theme by default. What you want is Java's GTKLookandFeel theme. Normally you would be able to do this by starting yEd with:

```
java -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel -jar yed.jar
```

Due to a bug in yEd/Java this does not work currently. For now you will have to apply the 
following workaround:

1.) Navigate to yEd's installation folder

```
cd $HOME/.yed
```

2.) Edit yed.jar and delete the class causing the theme issues

```
mv yed.jar yed.zip
zip -d yed com/jgoodies/looks/plastic/Plastic3DLookAndFeel.class
mv yed.zip yed.jar
```

You can now start yEd in GTK mode.

With some Java versions you might run into a scenario where all fonts in the GTK theme are formatted in bold. You can troubleshoot this by uninstalling a korean font package:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge  fonts-unfonts-core
```

If you don't feel like removing packages just to troubleshoot Oracle's bugs you can try out the [workaround outlined in this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/937200/comments/44).

---

References:

http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/java-programm-yed-aussehen-anpassen/#post-5244382

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/937200